# AWS CloudFormation - Stack name list as Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to specify a list of Stack Names as a parameter in a CloudFormation template?

I've tried:

```
"Parameters": {
  "NetworkStackName": {
    "Type": "List<AWS::CloudFormation::Stack>"
  }
}
```

Also:

```
"Type": "List<AWS::CloudFormation::Stack::Id>"
[...]
"Type": "List<AWS::CloudFormation::Stack::StackName>"
[...]
"Type": "List<AWS::CloudFormation::Stack::StackName>"
[...]
"Type": "List<AWS::Stack>"
```

But no luck ... And can't find any documentation for anything other than listing `AWS::Ec2` resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any of `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`, `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack::Id`, `CloudFormation::Stack::StackName`, `AWS::Stack` as such a parameter types do not exist. You can find the available parameter types [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) (under "AWS-Specific Parameter Types").

Your parameter could be a `CommaDelimitedList`:

```
"Parameters": {
  "NetworkStackName": {
    "Type": "CommaDelimitedList"
  }
}
```

so that you can inject your stack names as a comma separated list string, e.g.

```
"stackName1,stackName2,stackName3"
```

Using this method, `NetworkStackName` will result in

```
["stackName1", "stackName2", "stackName3"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the list format in 'default' parameter! I was unable to find it in any other places